Custom Audio Device for Twilio Javascript SDK
Is there a similar approach to the Custom Audio Device using the Twilio Javascript SDK like the Android and iOS SDKs have?
I'm aware of the AudioWorkletProcessor framework to access the microphone stream (input) but is there a possibility to access the speakers stream from the person on the other size of the line?
The Twilio Streams API is always an option, I want to avoid that because of the lag but if that's the only option so be it
